# Can I have Ubuntu, Xubuntu and Lubuntu desktop sessions installed without having the applications from the one in the other?

Tags: session

When I install multiple sessions next to each other, the default programs from the one also appear in the other. How to prevent this?

I'm talking about ALL the default applications. I don't need multiple applications (Firefox, Chromium, Konqueror...) for the same task littering the applications menu. So I'd like to hide the default apps from one DE when using another DE which has a different default app.

Comment: What do you mean by "default programs", are you referring to the multiple applications say text editors (kate,gedit,etc) ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you maybe referring to multiple entries for the same program. `Evince` would be a good example because it is common to Lubuntu, Ubuntu and Xubuntu.

What you could do is to go into `/usr/share/applications` and hunt down "common" .desktop files. `Sudo` edit the "Name" lines to make them distinct if you wish or add `NoDisplay=True` to the end of whichever .desktop file you don't wish to see as an entry.

---

Based on your comment, it appears that if you're using KDE (for example, since you mentioned Konqueror in the comment), you don't want to see Firefox or Chromium in KDE menus.

There are two possible entries you can add to the relevant .desktop file. Use:

```
NotShowIn=KDE;
```

to prevent an app from being seen in a specific desktop environment, KDE, in this case.

Or, you could go the other way and add

```
OnlyShowIn=XFCE;
```

or

```
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
```

to restrict an app's visibility to a specific desktop environment, XFCE or Unity, for example..

In any case, do look at http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ for detailed information.

Just to be clear, I don't know of any way to do what you want automatically without the hassle of sudo editing each file.

Comment: No I'm talking about ALL the default applications. I don't neef multiple applications (Firefox chromium konqurer...) for the same task littering the applications menu. So I'd like to hide the default apps from the one from the another.